# how to sort an xml returned from webservice

Tags: javascript, xml

I am working on a project where I'm able to use just jQuery, Javascript and HTML CSS. So, XML response that I copied is below, and I want to sort this XML response on the basis of number of stars given to every location, with the highest number of stars on the top.

```
<Locations>
  <Location>
    <Id>790</Id>
    <Name>DHA Office</Name>
    <Latitude>31.4737</Latitude>
    <Longitude>74.3771</Longitude>
    <Distance>0.74</Distance>
    <Address>Sector Y</Address>
    <City>Lahore </City>
    <Subcategory>Convenience Store</Subcategory>
    <Appid>1</Appid>
    <Stars></Stars>
    <Options>2,,,,,,,,,,</Options>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Id>729</Id>
    <Name>McDonald's</Name>
    <Latitude>31.4749</Latitude>
    <Longitude>74.3772</Longitude>
    <Distance>0.67</Distance>
    <Address>486/ B</Address>
    <City>Lahore </City>
    <Subcategory>Convenience Store</Subcategory>
    <Appid>1</Appid>
    <Stars>5</Stars>
    <Options>3,,,,,,,,,,</Options>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Id>732</Id>
    <Name>Lahore Zoo</Name>
    <Latitude>31.5563</Latitude>
    <Longitude>74.3261</Longitude>
    <Distance>4.79</Distance>
    <Address>92 Mall Road</Address>
    <City>Lahore </City>
    <Subcategory>Convenience Store</Subcategory>
    <Appid>1</Appid>
    <Stars>3</Stars>
    <Options>6,7,,,,,,,,,</Options>
  </Location>
</Locations>
```

Comment: You can't sort in CSS, but you can do it in jQuery... see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052775/how-to-sort-xml-data-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with ordinary XML in jQuery.

```
var l = $(yourXmlString).find('Location');
l.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (
    parseInt($(b).children('Stars').first().text()) - 
    parseInt($(a).children('Stars').first().text()));
});
```

Comment: Hmm... try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/prwpk/), it shows the code usage

Comment: if you dont mind can i ask more regarding the topic? i had a page on which i show these records.........first time when page loads in the document.ready i am showing every record directly then i had two buttons on which i call functions to show by rating or distance , now the problem is page load thing is always executed and secondly these records get cancatenated ...... any hint to set the situation?

Comment: Well, if you subsequently fill the container/placeholder when your Ajax response is returned, just call [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) on your container/placeholder before you fill it. However, if you ask another question you could get more responses. And possibly some points if you ask it properly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, you could convert this XML to an array of object and then sort that array based on your desired criteria. You could then show the information from this sorted array of objects. Normally you wouldn't need the sorted XML, but only have the information sorted.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111395/javascript-xml-data-to-associative-array) post on how you can convert `XML` to `associative array`.

You could then apply the JavaScript sort function with your [defined compare function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

Answer (score 0):

how about a plugin to parse the xml: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-xml2json-plugin/

Then...

```
var locations = $.xml2json(response);
console.log(locations)
locations.Location.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseInt(a.Stars || "0") > parseInt(b.Stars || "0");
});

$.each(locations.Location,function(k,v){console.log(v.Stars);});
```

outputs to the console:  3 5

http://jsfiddle.net/5Cbvc/

Comment: cant we doi it directly from xml?